# update/delete event for Kendo UI Grid Aurelia

Tags: grid, kendo-grid, aurelia

The update/create/delete events are not getting fired. Any idea?

View:

```
  <ak-grid k-option.bind = "gridOptions" id="adminGrid"  k-toolbar.bind="['create']" k-editable.bind="true"  k-pageable.bind="true" k-sortable.bind="true">
                       </ak-grid>
```

View Model:

```
  activate(params) {
        this.name = params.type.toUpperCase();

        return this.getData(this.getType(), null).then(items => {

            this.getMetadata(items)
                .then(metadata => {
                    this.gridOptions = metadata;
                });
        });


    }
     getMetadata(items) {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve({
                    columns: this.getColumns(items),
                    autoSync: true,
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: //alert("read"),
                            function (e) {
                                e.success(items);
                            },
                            update:
                            function (e) {
                                alert("update"),
                                    e.success(e.data);
                            },
                            destroy: function (e) {
                                alert("delete");
                            },
                            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                if (operation == "create") {
                                   alert("create param");
                                }
                                return options;
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 10,
                        editable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            pageSizes: true
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```